# Calculating decile ranks within by groupings in R

Tags: r

I have a series of financial company returns with other characteristics. Header of data are:

head(companyReturnsNameScore)

```
  PERMNO     date TICKER     PRC   VOL       RET SHROUT
1  85814 19980831  CTAC  6.1875 27989 -0.489691   6431
2  85814 20021231  CTAC 27.5700 97498  1.177725  11388
3  85814 19990129  CTAC 14.7500  5658 -0.180556   6275
4  85814 20021031  CTAC  9.0300 20192 -0.097000  11382
5  85814 20021129  CTAC 12.6600 15474  0.401993  ...
  marketCap marketCapDeclile
1  39791.81                2
2 313967.16                6
3  92556.25                4
4 102779.46                4
5 152958.12                5
```

---

I can calculate the market capitalization decile rank (1 to 10) over the entire period, which you see in the 'marketCapDecile' variable.  I use the 'decile' function in the 'StatMeasures' package as an easy way to get the decile ranks, but when I attempt to use the function to get decile ranks by date, I get the following error:

> by(companyReturnsNameScore,companyReturnsNameScore$date,decile(companyReturnsNameScore$marketCap))
>   Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : could not find function "FUN"

The function 'decile' exists, because I can run without error outside the 'by...' operation, but when I place it inside, I get the error.

How can I generate decile ranks of 'marketCap' by date with the 'by' function. I am willing to not use the 'decile' function, but when I try to use 'quantile,' or other tool, I do not seem to be able to generate the decile rankings...

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ugh... I  tried to get data in nice columns, but for some reason, didn't work. Sorry gang...

Answer (score 0):

One method is a combination of `quantile` with `findInterval`. `quantile`  together with the probs=1:10/10 arguement, will calculate the values at each decile, these values are fed to `findInterval`, which constructs the categories.

```
# set up dummy vector for example
temp <- 1:100
findInterval(temp, quantile(temp, probs=1:10/10), left.open=T)
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
[30] 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
[59] 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
[88] 8 8 8 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
```

Of course, just add 1L to the result if you want deciles 1 through 10.

Answer (score 0):

`decile` will always throw a warning if the input factor has length < 2. I updated your test data frame to have multiples of date.

```
   PERMNO     date TICKER     PRC   VOL       RET SHROUT        mc
1:  85814 19980831   CTAC  6.1875 27989 -0.489691   6431  39791.81
2:  85814 20021031   CTAC 27.5700 97498  1.177725  11388 313967.16
3:  85814 19980831   CTAC 14.7500  5658 -0.180556   6275  92556.25
4:  85814 20021031   CTAC  9.0300 20192 -0.097000  11382 102779.46
5:  85814 20021031   CTAC 12.6600 15474  0.401993   6400 152958.12
```

I'd use `library(purrr);library(dplyr)` instead of `by` for this scenario, because of `by` requiring functions that will work on the entire data frame.

```
df %>% split(.$date) %>% map_df(~ mutate(., date_decile = decile(mc)))
  PERMNO     date TICKER     PRC   VOL       RET SHROUT        mc date_decile
1  85814 19980831   CTAC  6.1875 27989 -0.489691   6431  39791.81           1
2  85814 19980831   CTAC 14.7500  5658 -0.180556   6275  92556.25          10
3  85814 20021031   CTAC 27.5700 97498  1.177725  11388 313967.16          10
4  85814 20021031   CTAC  9.0300 20192 -0.097000  11382 102779.46           1
5  85814 20021031   CTAC 12.6600 15474  0.401993   6400 152958.12           5
```

Comment: Thanks @nathan-day. Actually, I figured how to make decile run without error. I simply needed to have the function call with no arguments:

Comment: The problem I have is now capturing those decile ranks
> companyReturnsNameScore$marketCapDecileRank<-by(companyReturnsNameScore$marketCap, companyReturnsNameScore$date, decile)

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "marketCapDecileRank", value = list( : 
  replacement has 1080 rows, data has 1785812
-------------------------------------

How can I capture those ranks for each date/marketcap value combination?

Comment: you can either pair down your original(big) data frame so that it only has one row per date, or your could merge in the decile ranks so that the big data frame would just have the same decile value for each observation(row) of a specific date.